# Incorrect data value in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE if exists mzeng.test2//
CREATE  PROCEDURE mzeng.test2(TerminalName VARCHAR(25),tablename varchar(25), SetStartDate datetime,  SetEndDate datetime)

BEGIN
SET @t1 =CONCAT('create view mzeng.',tablename,' as SELECT * FROM ',TerminalName,'.restaurants where lud_dtm >= ', SetStartDate,' and lud_dtm < ',SetEndDate);

PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

end//
DELIMITER ;

call mzeng.test2('otg_ewrc1', 'EWRc1_TransactionalTable2','2017-07-01 04:00:00','2017-07-02 04:00:00');
```

The data type for the date here should be 'datetime'. However, when i call the procedure, it returns error code saying something to check the right syntax.

when I change the data type for the start date and end date to 'date', the call returns error message saying incorrect date value. The view is created though, but it is empty.

First time using this website. Thanks guys.

-------------------update --------------

I found the solution. it is just simply adding " this before and after the date.
  --- where lud_dtm >= "', SetStartDate,'" and lud_dtm < "',SetEndDate,'";')

Took me hours to find out. lol

Comment: You can't create views using dynamic table names in procedures. Prepared statements must not contain DDL instructions (such as create view, create table or similar), only DML instructions are allowed

Comment: I am sure i can. I have another query that does not need to use date as parameters, and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the single quote character (') to enclose  the datetime string.

```
SET @t1 =CONCAT('create view mzeng.',tablename,' as SELECT * FROM '
      ,TerminalName,'.restaurants '
      ,'where lud_dtm >= \'', SetStartDate,'\' and lud_dtm < \'',SetEndDate,'\'');
```

The restult after concatenate:

```
"... lud_dtm >= '2017-07-01 04:00:00' and lud_dtm < '2017-07-02 04:00:00' "
```

Comment: Yes. it is. and " work as well. Darn it. Took me hours to figured out.

Comment: Except... you should never do this manually.  That's what the [`QUOTE()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) is for.  `'where lud_dtm >= ', QUOTE(SetStartDate,), ' and...` is the correct answer.  It is not vulnerable to SQL injection and correctly handles NULL (which this answer does not).